# How to display the v-alert again once the close button is clicked in Vuetify?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using a dismissible `v-alert` and on closing the alert it should again display after 2 hours.
I tried with a `snack bar` as well but no output.
I am trying to hide and show `v-alert` based on time.

```
<v-alert
 border="left"
 close-text="Close Alert"
 color="deep-purple accent-4"
 dark
 dismissible
 text-align ='center'
>
 Total call list - 118 And Yet to call list - 80
</v-alert>
```

Can you please look into it?

@Neha

```
  watch: {
    alert (newVal) {
      if (!newVal) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.alert = true
        }, 600000)
        setInterval(() => {
          this.alert = true
          this.totalAndYetToCallCounts = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('getTotalAndYetToCallCount'))
        }, 1000)
      }
    }

  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is mentioned in the [documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/alerts/#dismissible)-

> You can restore the alert by binding `v-model` and setting it to true.

Here is the working demo of-

**If you want to manually open an alert (use a button to toggle it)-**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <v-app>
        <v-alert
          v-model="alert"
          border="left"
          close-text="Close Alert"
          color="error"
          dark
          dismissible
          class="mx-15"
          >
          Hello, I am an alert.
        </v-alert>
        <div class="text-center">
          <v-btn
            v-if="!alert"
            color="red"
            dark
            @click="alert = true"
            >
            Re-open
          </v-btn>
        </div>
      </v-app>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
    <script>
      new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        vuetify: new Vuetify(),
        
        data () {
      return {
        alert: true,
      }
      },
      })
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**If you want to open after a particular time (use any time function to monitor)-**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <v-app>
        <v-alert
          v-model="alert"
          border="left"
          close-text="Close Alert"
          color="error"
          dark
          dismissible
          class="mx-15"
          >
          Hello, I am an alert.
        </v-alert>
        <div class="text-center mt-5" v-if="!alert">
          WAIT FIVE SECONDS FOR IT TO RE-OPEN ⏳
        </div>
      </v-app>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
    <script>
      new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        vuetify: new Vuetify(),
        data () {
          return {
            alert: true,
          }
        },
        watch: {
              alert(newVal) {
                  if (!newVal) {
                      setTimeout(() => {
                          this.alert = true;
                      }, 5000);
                  }
              },
          },
      })
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**An Important Tip-**

An event (something like a notification) should be triggered from the backend that two hours have passed since closing the alert and on that event's listening the client should re-open the alert.
To depend only on the client side to do this job can be unsuccessful because on the client side the time will restart once the page loads.

Comment: I have improvise my code <template>
  <div>
    <v-app light>      
    <v-alert
      border="left"
      close-text="Close Alert"
      color="deep-purple accent-4"
      dark
      dismissible
      text-align ='center'
      v-model="alert"
    >
      Total Lead - 118 And Yet to call leads - 80
    </v-alert>
    </v-app>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      alert: true
    }
  },

  async created () {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('here')
      this.alert = true
    }, 2000)
  }

}
</script>

Comment: But once I close the popup again it's not getting open after a particular time. So, my requirement is like initially alert should be displayed then clicked on cross/close button then it should close and again open after sometime.

Comment: What is your vue version?

Comment: I updated the code, instead of the `created` hook, I used the `watcher`. Once you close, wait for five seconds, and it will reopen. Again if you will close, wait for 5 seconds and it will re-open, and so on. Please check the updated demo and let me know if it helps.

Comment: I check version using " npm list vue" which is vue@2.6.14

Comment: Please see my last comment, and update me.

Comment: Yes! Now it is working perfectly fine. So, can you please explain when we wrote in created hook it didn't work but worked with watchers. How?

Comment: Yes, when using the created hook, the timer is set only once, which means once we close the alert manually, it will open again after 5 seconds, and the job of the created hook is completed. But if you close the alert again then there is no timer that is monitoring this. That's why the alert re-opens only once.

Comment: On another hand, when we use watcher, the watcher will run whenever the alert status is false, and if it false, it will set the timer to reopen it after 5 seconds. So, the benefit of watcher we get it to always monitor the alert when it is false. That's why used, `if(!newVal)` which means setting the timer only if the alert is false.

Comment: Okay! Got it. Now it became very easy to understand. Thank you so much. If I got any query/doubt related to other stuff how will be I able to connect with you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250582/discussion-between-neha-soni-and-kiran).

Comment: is it possible to auto refresh alert without closing.We can also set an interval for auto refresh

Comment: Yeah, use the same function set timeout and write your refresh code inside that.

Comment: I have shared you my code above. Do you mean that way?

Comment: What I am trying to do is after every 1 sec value in v-alert should be updated from locaStorage and if I close the alert it should reopen after 10 mins

Answer (score 0):

you should add **:value** to alert

```
<v-alert type="success" :value="alert">
    I'm a success alert.
  </v-alert>
```

later

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data(){
    return{
       alert: true,
    }
  },
  created(){
    setTimeout(()=>{
      this.alert=false
    },5000)
  }
})
```

It beats every 5 seconds, you update here

Comment: Highly appreciated for your input.
In this case v-alert will automatically close after 5 sec but in my case it should close when close button is clicked and re-display after 2 hours